# Get NancyResponse content body before returning the view

Tags: c#, nancy

is it possible to get the NancyResponse body before returning the View?

I mean this:

```
Get["/"] = x => {
                var x = _repo.X();
                var view = View["my_view", x];
                **//here I want to send the response body by mail**
                return view;
            };
```

Comment: I see that is has an 'AsAttachment' extension

Comment: That makes the browser download the response.

Comment: yes, I see, it only overwrites the contet type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Watch out!** this answer is based on nancy version **0.11**, a lot has changed since then. The version within the route should still work. The one in the after pipeline not if you use content negotiation.

You could write the contents to a memorystream in the route or you could add a delegate to 
the After Pipeline:

```
public class MyModule: NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = x => {
            var x = _repo.X();
            var response = View["my_view", x];
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                response.Contents(ms);
                ms.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;
                //now ms is a stream with the contents of the response.
            }
            return view;
        };

        After += ctx => {
           if (ctx.Request.Path == "/"){
               using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
               {
                   ctx.Response.Contents(ms);
                   ms.Flush();
                   ms.Position = 0;
                   //now ms is a stream with the contents of the response.
               }
           }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm I'm just noticing that there is no ctx.Response.Body stream

Comment: it seems that the response here is the same as in the handler

Comment: good, thank you again, what do you think about putting this directly inside the Get[] handler instead of on the After? what's the purpose of having it there?

Comment: @JackNova Updated the question to include getting the response within the route.

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.Negotiator' does not contain a definition for 'Contents'

Answer (score 1):

`View[]` returns a `Response` object and that has a `Content` property of the type `Action<Stream>` so you could pass in a `MemoryStream` into the delegate and it would render the view in that stream

Answer (score 1):

I use Nancy version 0.17 and @albertjan solution is based on 0.11.
Thanks to @TheCodeJunkie he introduced me to the `IViewRenderer`

```
public class TheModule : NancyModule
{
    private readonly IViewRenderer _renderer;

    public TheModule(IViewRenderer renderer)
    {
           _renderer = renderer;

           Post["/sendmail"] = _ => {

                string emailBody;
                var model = this.Bind<MyEmailModel>();
                var res = _renderer.RenderView(this.Context, "email-template-view", model);

                using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() ) {
                  res.Contents(ms);
                  ms.Flush();
                  ms.Position = 0;
                  emailBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( ms.ToArray() );
                }

                //send the email...

           };

    }
}
```